# ErrorItemNotFound for Sent Items message notification

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have created a subscription for all mailbox folders as

```
users/email@email.email/messages?$filter=isDraft eq false
```

When creating a subscription the Prefer header is specified: IdType = "ImmutableId".
The problem is that for all folders via the webhook we successfully receive a notification with an immutable ID and get by this ID email using Graph messages API, but in the case of emails sent from Outlook, the webhook first receives the ID, which triggers an error on Message get:
`Status Code: NotFound Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ErrorItemNotFound Message: The specified object was not found in the store., Item not found.`
After this, the second webhook associated with the Sent Items folder arrives. I don't know what the first webhook is related to, possibly the Outbox folder. How can this be overcome?

Comment: I see that you subscribed to all mailbox folders. Say, when you create a new message, send it, then the subscription will get you the ID then this message will be moved to Drafts and then to Outbox, before it moved to Sent items. Hence, i suspect you're see this error - as its telling the item's not found in the store (as it was moved from one folder to another).

Comment: In order to debug further you can use tool like ngrok to see what's happening :)

Comment: I can see in debug that I receive this id and exception on message getting. There is no other useful data like folder id in webhook notification object. Most likely its Outbox. The only solution I see now is to specify filter by this folder during subscription registration. But it's really smells like a crutch.

Comment: As i updated above, due to the flow you see this behavior. You may want to handle the error at your end and skip it if its the same id.

Comment: We don't control the sending of emails. They are sent manually, externally. All ids for us are new. And first id related to Outbox is different from id related to Sent items. We only can catch all such exceptions and skip all cases.

Comment: Yeah, i understand your scenario :)